# Password error when trying to use sendmail as smtp out server

Tags: smtp, sendmail

I´m trying to setup a sendmail server to receive and sent messages using it.

The first part is done, but now I will want to use it to send (setting it as smtp in thunderbird for example), but when I try to send one, it asks me for the smtp password.

The smtp user is a user which can receive mail in thunderbird, so the password is fine. But it seems that the smtp out password is not the same...

Any idea of what do I need to do in order to achieve it? Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Sendmail doesn't have SMTP set up by default. See the "Sending mail from your PC: The Nitty Gritty" section of [this page](http://rimuhosting.com/support/settingupemail.jsp?mta=sendmail) (and possibly the pages it points to) for information on setting up SMTP authorization with Cyrus SASL. Also see the section "Make your SMTP server public" in case that applies. The page discusses setup on their VPS, but the principles still apply.